# How to make a PROCEDURE that extracts part of a string?

Tags: oracle, plsql

How could I get parts of a string using a PROCEDURE?
For example, I receive a string containing the email address: name@email.com

I want to separate each information from the email on a line:

Address: name

Domain: email

location: .com

I tried using SUBSTR but I was only able to return the first information.

```
set serveroutput on;
    create or replace procedure pr_getsubstring (email varchar2)
    as
    text varchar2(300) := 0;
    begin
        for x in 1 .. length (email) loop
        if substr (email, x, 1) = '@' then
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Address:' || text);
            exit;
            else text: = 'Address:' || text || substr (email, x, 1);
            end if;
        end loop;
    end;
            
    
    call pr_getsubstring('hello@word.com');
```

Result returned:

Address: hello

Expected outcome:

Address: hello

Domain: word

Local: .com

Comment: Post what you've tried in a form that's easy for someone to reproduce what you're tried. Give example input and desired output.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_getsubstring(email varchar2)
AS 

TYPE EMAIL_TOKENS IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);
et EMAIL_TOKENS;
BEGIN 
  
  SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(email, '[^@.]+', 1, LEVEL) BULK COLLECT INTO et 
  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(email, '[^@.]+');
  
 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Address: '||et(1));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Domain: '||et(2));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Local: .'||et(3));
  
END;
```

Comment: This code would not work properly if there were any extra periods in the email address such as `first.last@gmail.com` or `someemail@subdomain.domain.com`

Comment: No it will work fine,  substrings are created either on @ or .

Comment: John.carter@gmail.com or john.carter@google.gmail.com It is working and I have verified.

Comment: the tokens will be split by the select statement, but using john.carter@gmail.com, the domain will be printed as carter which is incorrect. In this case, the address consists of the first two tokens, the domain is the 3rd token, and the local is the 4th token.

Comment: Yup, if you mean identifying tokens as per the requirement will be an overhead, agree on that. if the format of email varies then code needs tweaking but that is something not explicit mentioned by the OP then I guess code is fine for now.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to split the string using substrings. You can remove the `SUBSTR` logic from the query below and use it in a PL/SQL procedure if you need.

```sql
WITH
    d (email)
    AS
        (SELECT 'name@email.com' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'testemail@subdomain.domain.gov' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'another@co.uk' FROM DUAL)
SELECT email,
       SUBSTR (email, 1, INSTR (email, '@') - 1)
           AS address,
       SUBSTR (email, INSTR (email, '@') + 1, INSTR (email, '.', -1) - INSTR (email, '@') - 1)
           AS domain,
       SUBSTR (email, INSTR (email, '.', -1))
           AS location
  FROM d;

                            EMAIL      ADDRESS              DOMAIN    LOCATION
_________________________________ ____________ ___________________ ___________
name@email.com                    name         email               .com
testemail@subdomain.domain.gov    testemail    subdomain.domain    .gov
another@co.uk                     another      co                  .uk
```

Below is how to use the same logic in a PL/SQL procedure.

```sql
DECLARE
    PROCEDURE print_email (p_email VARCHAR2)
    IS
    BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Address: ' || SUBSTR (p_email, 1, INSTR (p_email, '@') - 1));
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
               'Domain: '
            || SUBSTR (p_email,
                       INSTR (p_email, '@') + 1,
                       INSTR (p_email, '.', -1) - INSTR (p_email, '@') - 1));
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Location: ' || SUBSTR (p_email, INSTR (p_email, '.', -1)));
    END;
BEGIN
    print_email ('name@email.com');
    print_email ('hello@word.com');
    print_email ('testemail@subdomain.domain.gov');
    print_email ('another@co.uk');
END;

Address: name
Domain: email
Location: .com
Address: hello
Domain: word
Location: .com
Address: testemail
Domain: subdomain.domain
Location: .gov
Address: another
Domain: co
Location: .uk
```